# Выгрузка блобов из MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Возник вопрос, как можно выгрузить блобы из MS SQL в цикле?

Есть возможность поштучной выгрузки, но непонятно, как это завернуть в цикл:

bcp "select blob from Photo where objectno in ('123456')" queryout "C:\XLS\out.jpg" -f "C:\XLS\bcpData.fmt" -S server -U user -P password -d photo

Comment: сделайте табличку с параметрами, воспользуйтесь динамическим sql скриптом и пройдите по таблице циклом.

Comment: Окей, а как в таком случае сделать так, чтобы файлы не перезатирались? Ведь мы в queryout указываем путь, куда необходимо сохранить конкретный файл.

Comment: ну это же тоже можно параметром